# Difference in behaviours of the Dispose method between Windows Forms' Form and textboxes

Tags: visual-studio

Whenever I call the `Dispose` method on a Windows Forms form (derived from System.Windows.Forms.Form) to close it, the `Dispose` method finalizes by releasing resources and disposing the form.

I have runtime objects like textboxes as below:

```
Textbox Tb = new Textbox();
```

The user can create new textboxes dynamically. I want it so those textboxes that contain data stay around, and those that are null are removed. When I call the `Dispose` method on the empty textboxes, at runtime it looks like they're disposed, but generally they're just invisible.

So:

1. What is the difference between calling the dispose method on textboxes versus classes derived from Forms?
2. Why is a Form disposed on calling e.g. `Form1.Dispose();`, and why not textboxes at runtime as below?

   ```
   if (tb.text=="")
       tb.Dispose();
   ```

Comment: it's for knowledge and everybody has right to gain it. then feel free to expanding knowledge.

Comment: I am here for knowledge not for points. and I do believe in this community.

Comment: @mahesh - I didn't downvote as I suspect that there is probably a reasonable question in there somewhere. However Downvotes are encouraged for questions that are unclear or not useful. Unfortunately this this question is indeed unclear (at least to me) due to the standard of English.

Comment: @Martin Smit, don't worry God will help u dear.

Comment: I'll have to agree with Martin, the question fails to make sense to me, even after reading it twice. Start with a new project, 1 Form and 1 Textbox. Post the code and tell us what happens and what you expected.

Comment: @Martin Smit am heartly apologize, i know my language is poor but am still wants to get answer of my question for my knowledge if u want than i will edit it. please tell me. am always ready for getting knowledge the knowledge does not have size like big and small. same way question is  important or not important but one think has to be clear that it should be answer.

Comment: @Henk Holterman Sir, I didn't get u. u are talking about this question.

Comment: mahesh, there may be a valid question here but nobody understands it. We need a smaller problem and a longer description.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, i am trying to solve it by else where thx for ur feedback.

Comment: Deleting upon request of the author.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63983/can-i-delete-my-own-question

Comment: Undelete Discussion http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64055/confusion-on-certain-comments-against-question-asked

Comment: @Michael Mrozek sir, thx for edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, it's because of ownership. The form owns the controls, so if you dispose of the controls, fine, you just need to refresh it. If you dispose of the form itself, it's gone, nothing to refresh.

Comment: Disposing a Control will surely invalidate its screen area.

Comment: @MPelletier sir, that means dispose method is specially design  or preapared only for form in case direct use. if it is use at runtime controls it's have to first get remove it from control and thenafter applied dispose method. In short dispose method's direct use for only forms.

Comment: @MPelletier sir, and direct use of dispose method on other controls like textboxes which harmful we will lose other controls resources espacially listbox control. it is very dangerous to use it without knowing about it. and we have to pay for it damages.

Comment: @mahesh: Form.close() usually takes care of all the disposing required. I will investigate further on how to remove a textbox properly.

Comment: I have found this question answer from some where else by two days before and i am satisfy with this my stackoverflow community thx all of u and i am apolozige against any bad thing if i created. Now if community wants to delete it than they are welcome to delete it. please.

Comment: But it's my Request that it is most important to knowing it to our new comer who don't aware of this type of problem. last Opinion i have leave up to our community.

Comment: This is rectification against my first comment : The winforms are closed directly on called dispose method where it is not same with other controls due to lac of access.